# What's the location of the private certificate store on Android version below 4.0?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app which reads a private certificate and key from the Android key store.

The certificate was imported on Android from a `.p12` file on the SD card using Settings > Security > Install from storage (Credential storage).

On version 4.0 and higher I can get certificate and key from Android [KeyChain](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html).

Can I programmatically get this certificate on Android version below 4.0?

I can see certificate and can choose it from WI-FI settings and that's all. 
I tried "BKS" and "PKCS12" stores, but get an empty resultset. I can access CA certificate store and get CA certificate data, but that is not what I need.

Answer (score 6):

The key and certificate are encrypted and stored in `/data/misc/keystore`. However, since they have been stored by the system, you don't have the permission to access or decrypt them. Additionally, there is no public API for this.

Comment: Thanks! You save a lot of my time to find a solution that is not.

Comment: If you are interested in the details, read this: http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2011/11/ics-credential-storage-implementation.html BTW, what are you trying to do?